# how do i extract 482,221 from this html code and store in excel or csv

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have this HTML element that I need to extract 482,221 using Selenium. It keeps on changing because it is a report that updates every hour.

```html
<td style="background-color:WhiteSmoke;min-width: 30.88mm;WIDTH:33.00mm;" class="Ac0548bab133f492498af53b0b728b012111c"><div style="word-wrap:break-word;white-space:pre-wrap;" class="Ac0548bab133f492498af53b0b728b012111">482,221</div></td>

<td style="background-color:WhiteSmoke;min-width: 30.88mm;WIDTH:33.00mm;" class="Ac0548bab133f492498af53b0b728b012111c"><div style="word-wrap:break-word;white-space:pre-wrap;" class="Ac0548bab133f492498af53b0b728b012111">482,221</div></td>>

<td style="background-color:WhiteSmoke;min-width: 30.88mm;WIDTH:33.00mm;" class="Ac0548bab133f492498af53b0b728b012111c"><div style="word-wrap:break-word;white-space:pre-wrap;" class="Ac0548bab133f492498af53b0b728b012111">482,221</div></td>
```

I tried XPath:

```py
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[@class='Ac0548bab133f492498af53b0b728b012111c']/div"))
)
value = element.text
print(value)  # should print 482,221
```

CSS Selector:

```py
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td.Ac0548bab133f492498af53b0b728b012111c > div"))
)
value = element.text
print(value)  # should print 482,221
```

by Class:

```py
# After performing the operations and landing on the desired page:
element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "Ac0548bab133f492498af53b0b728b012111")
value = element.text
print(value)  # should print 482,221
```

But I am getting this error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:50629/devtools/browser/d373f96e-11ec-4df1-ba1b-274fffb9510c Traceback (most recent call last): File "c:\Users\CHEEMN2\OneDrive - CPGGPC\Python\Main.py", line 43, in <module> element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\CHEEMN2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 95, in until raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:  Stacktrace: GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF600FD52A2+57122]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF600F4EA92]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF600E1E3AB]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF600E57D3E]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF600E57E2C]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF600E90B67]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF600E7701F]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF600E8EB82]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF600E76DB3]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF600E4D2B1]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF600E4E494] GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF60127EF82+2849794] GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6012D1D24+3189156] GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6012CACAF+3160367] GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF601066D06+653702]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF600F5A208]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF600F562C4]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF600F563F6]
        (No symbol) [0x00007FF600F467A3] BaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFDEB567614+20] RtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFDED2826B1+33]
```

Comment: Why aren't you looking for the `<div>` that actually contains the content?  Are you sure that class name isn't generated anew each time?

Comment: how do i do that I am pretty new to web scraping.
if you could please help me 

thanks

Comment: ??? Are you looking at the HTML?  Can you see that the `<div>` class is the same as the `<td>` except for the last character?

Answer (score 0):

use the style itself like this ;

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//div[@style='word-wrap:break-word;white-space:pre-wrap;']");
```

because the classname seems to be randomly generated , and try to increase the waiting because your code is timing out .